# How can I index document and search document on amazon S3

Tags: c#, indexing, amazon-s3, lucene.net

I am using lucene.net to index and search pdf on local system. How can I Index and search PDF on Amazon S3.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did research, There are too many ways you can achive this. One way is **CloudSearch**, indexing service which provide this functionality